# grouped_collection_select returns an error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a "grouped_collection_select" for a "branch" field, in combination with a "sector" field. Sector has_many branches and branch belongs_to sector:

```
<%= f.grouped_collection_select(:branch, current_user.company.sectors.order(:sector), :branches, :sector, :id, :branch, include_blank: true) %>
```

This works, but the ":branches" shows all branches and should only show the branches of the current_user.company, just like the sectord. But when I change ":branches" into "current_user.company.branches.order(:branch)", I get an error:

```
(eval):1: syntax error, unexpected $end group.#<ActiveRecord
```

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For clarity (and semantics) set that collection in your controller to use in your view:

```
 @sectors = current_user.company.sectors.order(:sector)
```

...or if you want to limit the branches that are showing for each sector by user, you'd probably want to build the collection based on the user's branches.  One example:

```
 @sectors = current_user.company.branches.collect{|b| b.sector}.uniq
```

Then assuming you want to set the branch_id AND a sector has a name attribute AND the branch has a name attribute, this should work:

```
 <%= f.grouped_collection_select(:branch_id, @sectors, :branches, :name, :id, :name, :include_blank=>true)

 #:branch_id is the attribute you will be setting on the form_builder's object.
 #@sectors is the collection of objects for the groups.
 #:branches is the method that will be called on each sector object.
 #:name is the method that will be called on each sector object to label the group.
 #:id is the method that will be called on each branch to set the option's value.
 #:name is the method that will be called on each branch to set the option's label.
```

Comment: It works alright, but it shows all branches in the database. It should only show the branches belonging to the current_user.company, just like sectors. But using @branches instead of :branches returns an error.

Comment: Using :branches is the equivalent of this expression:  "current_user.company.sectors.order(:sector).first.branches" Remember, :branches is the name of the method that will be called on each one of the sectors. Because of that, it can only be a string or a symbol.  Sounds like you're problem really is that you'll want to limit that @sectors collection based on the accessible branches for that user. For example, sectors = current_user.company.branches.collect{|branch| branch.sector}.uniq

Comment: Then my conclusion is that a grouped_collection_select is not what I can use. Instead I will use a collection_select and filter the values with jQuery based on the choice made in the sector listbox. But thanks for your explanation!